# Telerik Auto Complete textbox bind text and value

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have an auto complete text box . I am able to bind the the data to the text box .
I am able to retrieve the value and store it in the database .
Now I want know how do I bind the the saved value in the database to the auto complete text box again.
I tried somewhat like this

```
AutoCompleteBoxEntry childNode = new AutoCompleteBoxEntry();
childNode.Text = lblTeamLeaderName.Text;
childNode.Value = lblTASKTEAM_ID.Text;
txtusers.Entries.Add(childNode);
```

and

```
txtusers.Entries[0].Value = lblTASKTEAM_ID.Text;
txtusers.Entries[0].Text = lblTeamLeaderName.Text;
```

But still value which is saved is not being shown in the textbox .
I want to bind the text and value some what like dropdownlist box .
Can anyone tell where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 txtusers.Entries.Add(new AutoCompleteBoxEntry()
                        {
                            Text = lblTeamLeaderName.Text,
                            Value = lblTASKTEAM_ID.Text
                        });
```

Try this